# Select named element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this code

```
$('#addPhone').click(function() {
    phoneCount = $("#phoneTabs").tabs("length") + 1;
    $('#phoneTabs').show();
    $('#phoneTabs').append('<div id="phoneTabs' + phoneCount + '"><form id="phoneForm' + phoneCount + '" novalidate="novalidate" action="" method="post"><table><tr><td><b>Phone Number ' + phoneCount + '</b></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Phone number</td><td><input type="text" class="required digits" maxlength="10" minlength="10"  name="phone_number' + phoneCount + '" /></td></tr><tr><td>Comment</td><td><textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="phone_comment' + phoneCount + '"></textarea></td></tr></table><br /><button id="addPhone' + phoneCount + '">Add</button></form></div>');

    $("#phoneForm" + phoneCount).validate({
        submitHandler: function() {
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#addPhone' + phoneCount).button();
    $('#addPhone' + phoneCount).click(function() {
        $(this).button({
            disabled: true
        });
        $('#phoneForm' + phoneCount + ' input').attr('disabled', true);
    });

    $("#phoneTabs").tabs("add", "#phoneTabs" + phoneCount, phoneCount);
    $('#phoneTabs').tabs("select", phoneCount - 1);
    phoneCount++;
});​
```

Why when i click on addPhone button only the button get disabled, why the other input elements that are child of #phoneForm'+ phoneCount are not disabled?

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: It's better to use either `.prop("disabled", true)` or `.attr("disabled", "disabled")`.

Comment: Seeing the rest of your code might help.

Comment: @Skystar3 You should really improve your code formatting skills.

Comment: .prop("disabled", true) or .attr("disabled", "disabled") ---tried both didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [closure issue](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml), `phoneCount` value changes before it is applied in the click handler, to remove the closure try this

```
$('#addPhone' + phoneCount).click((function(selector){ return function() {
    $(this).button({
        disabled: true
    });
    $(selector).attr('disabled', true);
}})('#phoneForm' + phoneCount + ' input'));
```

EDIT

If you want to use the value of `phoneCount` in the function then pass only that to the IIFE

```
$('#addPhone' + phoneCount).click((function(phoneCount){ return function() {
    if (phoneCount operator operand){
        code
    }
    $(this).button({
        disabled: true
    });
    $('#phoneForm' + phoneCount + ' input, other selectors').prop('disabled', true);
}})(phoneCount));
```

Comment: is this valid statements? $(selector).attr('disabled', true);
})('#phoneForm' + phoneCount + ' input'));

Comment: Yes, its an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). It starts from `(function(selector){`

Comment: Firebug: missing ; before statement 
})Arrow here('#phoneForm' + phoneCount + ' input'));

Comment: it worked but it only disabled the first input element under #phoneForm' + phoneCount

Comment: @Skystar3 There is only one input element in your code,a `button` and a `textarea` is not an `input`

Comment: true ...i got working by   ('#phoneForm'
                   + phoneCount
                   + ' input,#phoneForm'
                   + phoneCount
                   + ' textarea'));   ....Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain to me what is exactly: Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)?

Comment: Its basically calling a function as it is defined, `(function(parameter){...}(passed))` the function is called with passed as an argument. The returning a function part has nothing to do with IIFE, its just to have a function without the `phoneCount` closure

Comment: Also How can i add if statement the following not working: $('#addPhone' + phoneCount)
             .click(
               
if($('#phoneForm' + phoneCount).valid()){
 function(selector) {
  return function() {
   $(this)
     .button(
       {
        disabled : true
       });
   $(selector)
     .attr(
       'disabled',
       true);
  }
 }
}

                 )
                 ('#phoneForm'
                   + phoneCount
                   + ' input,#phoneForm'
                   + phoneCount
                   + ' textarea'));

Comment: basically i want to run function(selector) if($('#phoneForm' + phoneCount).valid()) evaluate to true...how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

It could be disabling the inputs on the LAST tab, if you change the line

```
$(this).button({disabled : true});
$('#phoneForm'+ phoneCount+ ' input').attr('disabled',true);
```

to be

```
$(this).button({disabled : true});
$(this).closest("form[id^='phoneForm'])".filter('input').attr('disabled',true);
```

should hopefully get the form that is active.